# docker container nginx and npm http-server

Tags: docker, dockerfile

nginx is running in the container, how can I run npm `http-server` and visit it on a browser?

Dockerfile is very simple just to install nginx, nodejs and npm, `EXPOSE 80` `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`
root folder is `/var/www/`

Now I can create a container 
`docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name dotker dotker`

then I get inside docker container, 
`docker exec -it dotker bash`

I am able to navigate `/www/helloWorld` and run `http-server -p 8081`
Is it possible to view `/helloWorld` webpages on a browser as the port is being occupied by nginx?

Comment: You don't have to run `http-server -p 8081` from inside the container, you can specify this in Dockerfile and expose 8081 port.
Probably you can share your Dockerfile to help you better.

Comment: The better way is to have different container for different services, like in your case you can have nginx in one container and your app in another then you can use [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to communicate between the services.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look

Comment: you can refer to this tutorial [docker nginx node](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I was thinking the way is different, I was thinking to have a container like a Linux system so I can get inside but communicate with windows folder/files.Now I understand that the way I was thinking is not how docker container works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run any server when run container.

I'd suggest to add entrypoint script

to Dockerfile:

```
COPY /docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tiny", "--","/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

In docker-entrypoint.sh

All you running scripts. Something like:

```
http-server -p 8081
```